# Почему react не видит путь к видео?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Есть массив с данными секций:

```
import girljars from "../../videos/animations/girl-jars.mp4"

const DatabaseSections = [
    {
        id: 1,
        ...
        ...
        bg_video: girljars
    }
...
]
```

Под многоточием скрыты другие свойства. Секция выглядит так:

```
function DatabaseSection({ id, ..., bg_video }) {

return (
<section key={id} className={classes} id={text_id}>
    <video src={bg_video} width="800" height="800" autoPlay playsinline loop='true' className='section__bg'></video>
</section >
...
)

}
export default DatabaseSection
```

Почему когда я передаю в видео в свойства:

```
{
DatabaseSections.map((dataItem) => {
return <DatabaseSection bg_video={dataItem.bg_video}></DatabaseSection>
})
}
```

src теряется?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но когда импортирую видео в компонент DatabaseSection, src атрибут есть. При этом картинки .png импортирует спокойно из массива с данными?

Comment: Покажите что выводит в консоли переменная `girljars`